# Download Object From S3 Without Saving File to Temporary Directory - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to download several images from an AWS S3 bucket without going through the hassle of saving them in jpeg / png format in the device's temporary files. AWSS3GetObjectRequest seems to be the right way to start, but I am completely lost as to how we could implement such a process in Swift. 
The goal would be to download data from S3 and to convert it directly into a UIImage.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage. Follow this link may it help u.

Comment: Hello Yagnesh, this git looks interesting but I would like to handle my downloads through the AWS SDK if at all possible...

Comment: U just have to assign AWS image url with bucket name to sdWebImage it will download image and manage in cache memory.